# converting milliseconds to amount of time string

Tags: php

So pretty much I'm storing the amount of play time a player has in milliseconds and I need to convert it to the amount of time it equals (string).

I've already tried it but I can't seem to get it to be accurate. I used rounding and it turned out poorly.

Can anybody help me out?

Example: 183547165 -> * days * hours * minutes * seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP has a date function which do what you want:

```
date("H:i:s", '183547165');
```

It outputs:

```
09:19:25
```

[PHP DATE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 4):

If I'm reading the question right, then I think you want something like this!

```
<?php
$milliseconds = '183547165';
$time = $milliseconds / 1000;
$days = floor($time / (24*60*60));
$hours = floor(($time - ($days*24*60*60)) / (60*60));
$minutes = floor(($time - ($days*24*60*60)-($hours*60*60)) / 60);
$seconds = ($time - ($days*24*60*60) - ($hours*60*60) - ($minutes*60)) % 60;
echo $days.' days<br>'.$hours.' hours<br>'.$minutes.' minutes<br>'.$seconds.' seconds';
?>
```

Converts milliseconds to days, hours, minutes, and seconds.